# IE7 comes up blank on Virtual PC

Tags: internet-explorer-7, browser, virtual-pc

I'm having to troubleshoot a website in IE7 (I currently have IE8 installed on my machine). I've installed Virtual PC and the IE7-on-XPSP3.exe file, but when I run the virtual machine,  open IE7, and direct it to any page, it returns a blank screen. I know that there is some connection to the internet because it gets as far as grabbing the webpage's title and displaying it in the title-bar and tab, but then stops with a white page.

Has anyone come across this before, or can anyone suggest any solutions?

TIA,
Greg

EDIT: Actually it occasionally works, but occasionally IE crashes. I think the problem might have something to do with a message which pops up in the Virtual PC's taskbar: "Windows - Out of Virtual Memory. You system is low on virtual memory...'

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the development on Virtual PC has been halted, I suggest you to use VirtualBox by Sun, which works great and without problems. What your specific problem is with regards to IE7 within a virtual machine, it is hard to troubleshoot. I don't really know what the IE7-on-XPSP3.exe file is (?? haven't seen it yet) but it must be something wrong with it obviously.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The file I mentioned can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en#QuickDetails -- it's a virtual image of XP installed with IE7, developed by Microsoft to help browser testing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution - I just increased the virtual memory size following the instructions here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826513.

Thanks mare for your advice.